# Template parameter can't be deduced on implicitly constructed argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I would like to have the following code in c++17:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

class Foo;

template<class T>
class Bar {
public:

    std::function<T(Foo&)> m_fn;

    template<class Fn>
    Bar(Fn fn) : m_fn(fn) {};

    T thing(Foo &foo) const {
        return m_fn(foo);
    }
};


template<class Fn>
Bar(Fn) -> Bar<decltype(std::invoke(std::declval<Fn>(),
                                    std::declval<Foo&>()))>;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {};

    template<class T>
    std::vector<T> do_thing(const Bar<T> &b) {
        std::vector<T> r;

        r.push_back(b.thing(*this));

        return r;
    }
};


std::string test(Foo &) {
    return "hello";
}

int main() {
    Foo foo = Foo();

    // works
    std::vector<std::string> s = foo.do_thing(Bar{test});
    
    // cant deduce T parameter to do_thing
    std::vector<std::string> s = foo.do_thing({test});
}
```

But compiling this gives me "couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’" on the call to `do_thing`.
Having `do_thing(Bar{test})` fixes this and works fine but equates to some ugly code in the real code equivalent. I would like to have `do_thing({test})` or `do_thing(test)` implicitly construct a `Bar` and pass that as the argument if possible.

I also don't want to forward declare a variable to pass into `do_thing` either

Is there some way to guide the inference of template argument `T` so that the call to `do_thing` can stay clean?

## Edit:

Sorry for the late edit, but the arguments to the Bar constructor are over simplified in the example I included. In reality, there is an extra parameter `std::optional<std::string> desc = std::nullopt` and that might change in the future (although unlikely). So constructing the `Bar` inside `do_thing` would be a bit hard to maintain...

Comment: You can’t just accept the `T` and construct the `Bar<T>` in `do_thing`?

Comment: @DavisHerring yes but I'd like to avoid that. see my edit for explanation

Comment: FYI instead of `decltype(invoke(/*...*/))` use `invoke_result`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would like to have `do_thing({test})` or `do_thing(test)` implicitly construct a `Bar` and pass that as the argument if possible.

Unfortunately, when you call `do_thing({test})` or `do_thing(test)`, `test` (or `{test}`) isn't a `Bar<T>` object. So the compiler can't deduce the `T` type and can't construct a `Bar<T>` object.

A sort of chicken-and-egg problem.

The best I can imagine is to add, in `Foo`, a `do_test()` method as follows

```
template<typename T>
auto do_thing (T const & t)
 { return do_thing(Bar{t}); }
```

This way you can call (without graphs)

```
std::vector<std::string> s = foo.do_thing(test);
```

You get the same result as

```
std::vector<std::string> s = foo.do_thing(Bar{test});
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> is there any way of preserving the {test} brace syntax? maybe with initializer_list or something?

Yes... with `std::initializer_list`

```
template<typename T>
auto do_thing (std::initializer_list<T> const & l)
{ return do_thing(Bar{*(l.begin())}); }
```

but, this way, you accept also

```
std::vector<std::string> s = foo.do_thing(Bar{test1, test2, test3});
```

using only `test1`

Maybe a little better... another way can be through a C-style array

```
template <typename T>
auto do_thing (T const (&arr)[1])
 { return do_thing(arr[0]); }
```

This way you accept only an element.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way of preserving the `{test}` brace syntax? maybe with `initializer_list` or something?

Comment: @Neddy - answer improved; hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `{}` is not an expression and can only be used in limited ways while doing argument deduction, the parameter must have specific forms in order to succeed.

The allowed parameters types that can be used to deduce template parameters  when `{}` is involved are better expanded in **[[temp.deduct.call]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#1)**, two of the examples extracted from the cited part of the standard are:

```
template<class T> void f(std::initializer_list<T>);
f({1,2,3}); // T deduced to int

template<class T, int N> void h(T const(&)[N]);
h({1,2,3}); // T deduced to int
```

In your example the deduction guide is not used to deduce the `T` for `{test}` for the same as above.

```
foo.do_thing(Bar{test});
```

is your direct option without using additional functions.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what other ways `{}` will do argument deduction?